# DPI, Image width and height vs Quality

Tags: c#, image-processing, graphics, dpi

am creating a jpeg image using the following function

```
private static void Save(Bitmap bmp1, string path, ImageFormat format)
{
    bmp1.SetResolution(72,72);
    ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(format);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
    EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
    myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);

    bmp1.Save(path, jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
}

private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
{

    ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
    foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
    {
        if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
        {
            return codec;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

As you can see  I only play with the DPI from this line of code `bmp1.SetResolution(72,72);`

am wondering if the outputs look the same, how 72 DPI version will be suitable for the web and what's the true effect of DPI in this case 
Hint: Bitmap was generated of Bézier curve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, 72 DPI has been the default DPI for display devices.  300 for printing.

`SetResolution` doesn't actually change the appearance. *"[Use this method to set the desired resolution on a newly created bitmap. Changing the resolution of the image does not change its physical size.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setresolution(v=vs.110).aspx)"*.

It generally affects *"how big"* something will be when applied to a device.  Calling `SetResolution` has no effect on it's *[spatial resolution](http://micro.magnet.fsu.edu/primer/java/digitalimaging/processing/spatialresolution/)*.

When printing, you set the DPI for the image; for physical dimensions; and the map mode.  Attempting to print a 72 DPI image of a logical size of 210 mm x 294 mm on an A4 sheet of paper via 300 DPI laser printer will come out pixelated (because it was stretched to fill the whole sheet).

However if you maintain the DPI, and instead tell Windows that the image is really say 50 mm x 50 mm and print again to A4 on the same 300 DPI printer, it won't come out pixelated because it is closer to 1:1 (although now the image is rather small).

---

It is important to note that in the two examples above, the bitmap hasn't physically changed merely its meta dimensions and thus the resulting size on paper.

---

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, can you Illaborate more this sentence " It affects "how big" something will be when applied to a device."

Comment: @AMH there you go.  Again, this property shouldnt be a problem for web/display as displays are typically 72 DPI

Comment: Two notes: MSDN uses an ambiguous term imo: 'physical size' is meant to be about storage space on disk or in memory. But it can also be (mis)read as being about the size of printed output, which is at least as 'physical'.. Think of 'dpi' it as 'pixel size' - Also: Jpg will not allow crisp images for bezier curves or text ( which is mostly bezier as well) as it is meant for photogrpahs; I would consider using png instead.

Comment: One thing that notably _will_ decrease your image's quality, though, is using the lossy jpeg compression. And, no, putting its save quality to 100% doesn't change this. It'll just be a lot larger and still lossy. For a simple curve saved to an image, it's probably much better to use PNG.